# request issue when unit-testing webapp2 with mock and patch

Tags: python-2.7, unit-testing, google-app-engine, mocking

I'm building unit tests for this webapp2 handler (built for GAE)

```
    class PushNotificationHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def post(self):
            UserNotification.parse_from_queue(self.request)
            return

    app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        (r'/push/notification', PushNotificationHandler),
    ], debug=True)
```

One test is

```
    @patch.object(UserNotification, 'parse_from_queue')
    def test_post_webapp(self, p_parse_from_queue):
        response = webtest.TestApp(app).post('/push/notification')
        eq_(response.status_int, 200)
        p_parse_from_queue.assert_called_once_with(response.request)
```

The HTTP reply is OK, but the mock assertion fails:

```
    Expected call: parse_from_queue(<TestRequest at 0x105a89850 POST http://localhost/push/notification>)
    Actual call: parse_from_queue(<Request at 0x105a89950 POST http://localhost/push/notification>)
```

I can't understand why the request is not the correct one (looks like a deep copy). Is there anything wrong with the unit-test, or is that the way `webapp2` handle requests. In the second case, is there a way to test it, without creating a separate test to test `PushNotificationHandler.post()`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've used mock's `call_args` in a similar situation.  You can do something like this:

```
request = p_parse_from_queue.call_args[0][0]
self.assertEqual(request.url, "foo")
self.assertEqual(request.*, *)
```

The `[0][0]` gives you the first passed argument assuming that you are using ordered arguments and not keyword arguments.

You can then proceed to check other relevant attributes of the `request` object to make sure it is behaving as expected.